# Tversity DNLA services with Xbox 360

Tags: windows-server-2008, xbox360, timeout, dlna

I'm hosting a Tversity instance on my Windows 2008 server and sharing some media.  My PS3 detects this as a DNLA device and can play back the media just fine.

Tversity shows up on my Xbox 360, but when i click on it, it just loads and loads and after a minute it times out and tells me it can't connect.

Has anyone successfully gotten this working?

Answer (score 1):

What is the codec the video encoded with?  The Xbox 360 may not support that format, where the PS3 does.

Answer (score 0):

Its almost always caused by a firewall , well it has been for me at least. To test very quickly disable all firewalls on the PC and try connecting. Also i remember a 360 specific encoding option in the settings.

Comment: no firewall on the host PC.  360, PS3 and PC are on the same subnet.  Works fine on the PS3.